# Help wiring 2 Lutron Caseta dimmer switches

Tags: electrical

I'm attempting to wire 2 Lutron Casseta switches:

Lutron Caseta Switch:

[image]

Box:

[image]

4 wires feed into the box:

- Top two wires, one has three wires (black, white, ground) one has four wires (black, white, red, ground)
- Bottom two wires each have three wires (black, white, ground)

The Pink represents white wires

Comment: What kind of switches were in there previously and how were they connected?

Comment: What Caseta specifically are you using? And am I safe guessing that you want 3-way operation?